# Prove that if $ f $ is continuous on [a,b] and $ f$ is orthogonal

Tags: real-analysis

Prove that if  $ f $ is continuous on $[a,b]$ and $ f$ is orthogonal to all powers of $t$ , then $ f \equiv 0$ .

Since $f$ is orthogonal to all powers of $x$ , $ \int_{a}^{b} f(x) x^{n}dx=0 $ for all $n=1,2,3,\ldots $ From this how to conclude that $f$ is a zero function. **Any help is appreciated .**

Comment: Is $f$ real- or complex-valued? Are you familiar with the Stone-Weierstrass theorem?

Comment: Do you know that all continuous functions can be approximated uniformly by a polynomial?

Comment: yes,i know but how to execute the formula

Comment: Definitely a Stone-Weierstrass theorem problem.

Comment: I believe you have to include $n = 0$. If you do, then you can use the Stone-Weierstrass theorem.

Comment: @Aurel If it is true for $n>0$ then it is true for $g(x)=xf(x)$ and $n\geq 0$, so you can apply S-W to $g(x)$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

Note that if $p(x)$ is any polynomial, then $$\int_{a}^{b}xf(x)p(x)\,dx=0$$

Apply Stone Weirstrass to find $p(x)$ close enough to $xf(x)$ to ensure $\int xf(x)p(x)\,dx$ is positive if $\int |xf(x)|^2\,dx >0$.